# Django testing: post request with a Form with paramters

Tags: python, django, forms, testing, testcase

I want to test that my view redirects after I send it correct data. The problem is that I'm using a form that needs parameters while initializing. I have a method that builds me a response that I later use in the tests. The method works for my other views but I can't make it work with views that use Forms that need parameters to initialize them.

In my forms.py I have:

```
class SupportIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SupportIssue
        fields = ('user', 'property', 'title', 'text', 'is_urgent', 'is_service')

    def __init__(self, person_company, properties, is_property,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(SupportIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_service'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'custom-control-input'
        ...
```

My method for generating the response I'm later using in my test looks like this:

```
def generate_logged_in_user_post_response(self, data):
    request = self.factory.post(self.url, data={**self.form_class_args[0], **data})
    request.user = self.logged_in_user
    return new_support_issue_view(request)
```

I also tried this:

```
def generate_logged_in_user_post_response(self, data):
        form = SupportIssueForm(**self.form_class_args[0], data=data)
        request = self.factory.post(self.url, form)
        request.user = self.logged_in_user
        return new_support_issue_view(request)
```

the `self.form_class_args[0]` is some dictionary I declare elsewhere:

```
    {
        "person_company": person_company, # <query object>
        "properties": properties, # <query object>
        'is_property': False
    }
```

Comment: If your form class has `def __init__(self, person_company, properties, is_property, *args, **kwargs):`, then *the view* has to pass `person_company`, `properties` and `is_property`. You can't pass these values in the post data. Your question might be clearer if you show `new_support_issue_view` the result/errors when you run the tests.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. I realized that just after writing the question. The reason why the view didn't redirect was that the view had different methods for preparing the querryset used for Form initialization than the method I used to prepare it in my test. That's why the values I passed weren't in the choice set (choice set is generated based on the querryset passed to the Form while initializing it) thus the whole form was invalid and view didn't redirect.